# Is it known or where does this lead to?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am  eleventh class student, recently I started learning calculus. I was experimenting on various things, and found a new thing. It is as follows. Let us consider a function $f(x)$which is continuous. So we have derivative $f^{\prime}(x)$ of that function, and if we figure out all the values of the function, and the derivative there is an interesting linking between both of them.

That is  $$f(b)=f(b-1)+\left\lceil\dfrac{f^{\prime}(b)+f^{\prime}(b-1)}{2}\right\rceil$$ where $\lceil K\rceil$ is the ceil function of K. For example, let us consider $f(x)=x^3,f^{\prime}(x)=3x^2$ and we have $f(1)=1$, so $$f(2)=f(1)+\left\lceil\dfrac{f^{\prime}(2)+f^{\prime}(1)}{2}\right\rceil$$
$$f(2)=1+\left\lceil\dfrac{12+3}{2}\right\rceil=8=2^3$$

Some of my teachers told that its already known and it's called as mean value theorem, but 
I don't know whether it's already there or it's a new one, and what is the intuitive explanation for that ? It is useful in finding the next immediate point, to a given point. Generally we know that $f(a+h) \approx f(a) +f^{\prime}(a).h$, but how is this different from that ?

If it is a trivial question for experts present here, please do excuse me, but I will be happy in knowing the reason.

Thank you !

Comment: $1+\lceil\frac{12+3}{2}\rceil=1+8=9\ne 8$. Also note that introducing the ceiling function makes your property nonlinear and thus multiplying $f$ with a constant can make things fail even if thei were fine first.

Comment: This would imply that if $f(x)$ is differentiable then $f(b)$ is an integer whenever $f(b-1)$ is an integer.

Comment: This is definitely not the mean value theorem. Teachers like yours do students more harm than good by teaching false ideas rather than admitting what they do not know.

Answer (score 8):

One little remark: the statement " Let us consider a function $f(x)$ which is continuous. So we have derivative $f'(x)$  of that function..." is not true. Continuity of a function $f$ in a given point $x$ is not a sufficient condition for the differentiability of $f$ in that point.

Take for example  $f(x)=|x|$; it is continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable at that point, as the left derivative  and right derivative are different (in sign), as you can quickly check just using  definitions.

Comment: +1 for "Continuity of a function f in a given point x is not a sufficient condition for the differentiability of f in that point."but differen. of f on a point is sufficient for continuity

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work in general. Try $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $b=2$; or $f(x)=ax$ for some non-integer $a$, with any $b$.

Also, it turns out that not every continuous function has a derivative everywhere (in fact, some don't have a derivative *anywhere*), but you'll learn more about this as you progress.

Comment: Thank you, but at-least for integral powers of x, and integral coefficients of x, it will work. Why is that ? @Camaron Buie

Comment: No, it is not true for integral powers. As noted in the comment above, it is not even true for the example you gave: $\lceil 15/2\rceil \neq 7$. @SomPhene

Answer (score 4):

Or try $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x$, b = 1.

I would like to point out why this formula can't be possibly right:

$$f(x)=f(x-1)+\left\lceil\dfrac{f^{\prime}(x)+f^{\prime}(x-1)}{2}\right\rceil$$

it says that $f(x)-f(x-1)$ is **integer**. That would be very sad if we could only change our functions by integer value if we move by one in $x$-axis.

Comment: It does work for $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, because $f(1)=\frac{x}{2},f(2)=1, f^{\prime}(1)=\frac{1}{2}, f^{\prime}(2) = \frac{1}{2}$, so if you add them up and divide by $2$ you get $\frac{1}{2}$, and $f(2)-f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Som: But the ceiling of $\frac12$ is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

As Hagen pointed out above, this is not true even for the example you gave - you have a computational error.

It is true that if $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, then $$f(b)=f(b-1)+\frac{f'(b)+f'(b-1)-a}{2}$$ where $a$ is the coefficient of $x^3$ in the polynomial.

In particular, if $f(x)=x^3$ and $b$ is an integer, it thus means that we can show that:

$$f(b)=f(b-1)+\left\lfloor\frac{f'(b)+f'(b-1)}{2}\right\rfloor$$

This formula fails to work for general polynomials of degree higher than $3$, or for non-polynomial functions $f$.